# How to select all users I don't follow in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to build web app with Django on my backend and I want to make some type of people recommendations and show only people the current user doesn't follow, however I don't know how to do this.

It seems like there are questions on StackOverflow however they are about SQL queries and I still only know the Django Models for the database.

I use the standard Django User Model and the following model for the following relationship

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    # This means following(Person A) follows follower(Person B)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following')
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.following.username) + " follows " + str(self.follower.username)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('following', 'follower'), )
```

I use the following query to get all the users the current user follows, but I would like to sort-of invert it.

```
Follow.objects.filter(following=user.id).prefetch_related('following')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use exclude insteed of filter

```
Follow.objects.exclude(following=user.id).prefetch_related('following')
```

Comment: This doesn't work since this excludes only those follow relationships where I follow other people, and returns set of follow relationships, and I'm looking for set of users instead.

Comment: Oh, well you are using m2m between Users (thats what your model does)

You must make you query on User model

smth like (not sure about this one) :-) :
User.objects.exclude(follower=user.id)